# Typescript type of variable string yet still says it can be a string or null

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state

I have a state that is expecting a string variable. It's a search term. I'm getting this from the search url. But even when I'm checking to see if it's a string I still get an error saying that a variable of type string cannot be string | null

```
let searched = useLocation().search;
const query = new URLSearchParams(searched);
const [searchedTerm, setSearchedTerm] = useState<string>(typeof query.get('term') === 'string' ? query.get('term') : '');
```

I specificaly check if it's a string and then add it. The error that I get is this:

```
Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | (() => string)'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | (() => string)'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that typescript is preventing this, since it does not know if the function will return a `string` type again if it has done that in the first go.

Look at this example:

```
const random = () => {
let x = 3;
let arr = [2,'str'];
return arr[x%2];
};
const letX :string = typeof random() === 'string' ? random() : 'x';
```

The above will still throw the same error because the return type of the function might not be the same (since it technically can return a `number`, although we know it cannot).

So one simple solution would be to create an extra variable:

```
const random = () => {
let x = 3;
let arr = [2,'str'];
return arr[x%2];
};
const val = random();
const letY :string = typeof val === 'string' ? val : 'y';  
const letX :string = typeof random() === 'string' ? random() : 'x';
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgE4EMoBMIFsEF4EAUAlHgHwIDeoCCANgKaIAeeCAzANygOIpJKsA2gCYANAHJ4ScQF0uIJIwCuSKAj5JBTAKTC5oAL7zIsRADcUtVqgzZix6PDqMAmggBcUgJZQA5qzgATwAHeggAMwQLK1xYhEk4JB9fcQQAfijLD3jA8Q4aUBMnHgAND28-AJCwyJtMLGI8OISkv1SMursSd3imPJogA)